# Cannot install trac-batchmodify with apt-get

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, trac

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and trying to install Trac Batch Modify with the following command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y trac-batchmodify
```

But get the following error:

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   E: Unable to locate package trac-batchmodify

Is there any reason for this package not to be available via apt-get?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 14.04 provides Trac 1.0.1. Trac 1.0.1 include BatchModify functionality. The [BatchModifyPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/batchmodifyplugin) was integrated into Trac. See [TracBatchModify](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracBatchModify) for more info.